# Select text between quotes?

Tags: sublimetext3

It drives me mad. I can found how to select text between quotes in mac.
I have not installed any plugins. But i can select text pressing -

```
Ctrl + Shift + Space
```

Combination - `Ctrl + Shift + M` - fro selection text between brackets works good.

Please help me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a plugin specifically for this task: [`Expand Selection to Quotes`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Expand%20Selection%20to%20Quotes). Simply put your cursor between two quotes and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> to select the text between the quotes. Hit it again and it will select the quote marks themselves.

Comment: A very similar plugin is [Sublime Select Quoted](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Select%20Quoted)

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209841/5552584) the popular plugin [`BracketHighlighter`](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) has this built in. [Here's an example keymap](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/blob/master/Example.sublime-keymap).

Comment: The downside to this plugin (compared to BracketHighlighter) is that you can't bind some other hotkey to that action, so you're stuck with the left-hand-unfriendly `ctrl+'`.  Unless I'm missing something, which is entirely possible.

Comment: On MacOs you can use `CMD + SHIFT + SPACE`

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Plugin [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter) to achieve what you want. First, you need to install this Plugin. Then, go to `Preferences --> Key Bindings`.

[image]

Add the following key bindings,

```
{
        "no_outside_adj": null,
        "keys": ["ctrl+alt+super+s"],
        "command": "bh_key",
        "args":
        {
            "lines" : true,
            "plugin":
            {
                "type": ["__all__"],
                "command": "bh_modules.bracketselect"
            }
        }
}
```

Then you can use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to select texts between quotation marks.

Answer (score 7):

```
Ctrl + Shift + Space
```

works for me - it selects the text in quotes WITH quotes. But it's not a problem since I then just start typing quotes, and then what's inside...

No relevant plugins installed. Windows 10.

Comment: This worked perfectly. No need to install any plugins. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but it selects quotes as well.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out this, you can use plugin `BracketHighlighter` for this task.

Comment: Can you please expand this answer to explain exactly what you need to do in order to make it work?

Comment: I was also looking for this answer, using BracketHighlighter you can check the bindings in here https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/blob/master/Example.sublime-keymap or just add {
    "keys": ["alt+super+up"],
    "command": "bh_key",
    "args":
    {
      "no_outside_adj": null,
      "lines" : true,
      "plugin":
      {
        "type": ["__all__"],
        "command": "bh_modules.bracketselect",
        "args": {"always_include_brackets": true}
      }
    }
  } to your key bindings

Answer (score 4):

Sublime Text 3 (Build 4113) on OSX natively supports selecting many different kinds of text between quotes (ie, not just words, but also sentences, uuids, datetimes, and more) *without* selecting the quotes by clicking on the text inside the quotes that you want to select and using Selection > Expand Selection. Shortcut: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: This seems to work in any file that's _not_ HTML. If you're looking for this in HTML and have Emmet installed, try `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `,`. or `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `.`.